# Angular JS, update $scope from controller in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following situation:

In my app I have a quiz, I store the score and the current question as `$scope.current`, `$scope.score` in `MainCtrl`, then I have a directive called question where I show the question and the choices like:

```
angular.module('quiz')
    .directive('myQuestion', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                question: '=',
                index: '='           
            },

        link: function(scope) {



            scope.validate = function(index) {
                var isCorrect = index === scope.question.correct;

                if(isCorrect) {
                    console.log('Correct!');


                    //$scope.score += 10 ($scope score from MainCtrl)

                }

                if(!isCorrect) {
                    console.log('Incorrect!');

                    scope.correct = false;
                }

                //$scope.current += 1;

            };


            templateUrl: 'assets/javascript/tpl/question.html'
        };
    });
```

In my html I have the following structure:

```
<div class="quiz">

<h2>Current Question: {{current}}</h2>
<h2>Your score: {{score}}</h2>

<my-question ng-repeat="q in questions track by $index"
             ng-if="isCurrent($index)" //in controller i compare $index with $scope.current
             question="q"
             index="$index"></my-question>

</div>
```

My question is, how can I update `$scope.score` or `$scope.current` from the directive link function?

Can someone explain me please the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case where you have directive and want to update parent controller scope I think it would be best to use model with a dot `.`

For that you need to change model a bit in parent controller

```
$scope.quiz = {
  score: 0
  current: 0
}
```

then in directive you can do

```
$scope.quiz.score = 'whatever, really'
$scope.quiz.current = 'current index'
```

if you refer to a model like that `quiz.score` then it will not create `score` on current scope but instead it will find parent model `quiz` and change the `score`

Hope that makes sense

Comment: Damn it, I completly forgot about the KISS principle